# Is there a package or setting to show an org-mode link (under cursor) destination in the modeline or other area of Emacs window?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is there a package or setting to show an org-mode link (under cursor - without using the mouse) destination in the modeline or other area of Emacs window? It would be nice to have instead of doing C-c C-l to look at it each time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```lisp
(defun link-message () 
  (let ((object (org-element-context)))
    (when (eq (car object) 'link)
      (message "%s"
           (org-element-property :raw-link object)))))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'link-message)
```

Comment: Yes. I would like one associated with just the cursor as I don't use the mouse much.

Comment: Thanks a lot John Kitchin. Works great!

Comment: @JohnKitchin using `post-command-hook` can be a bit messy sometimes.  I think using text properties is a better bet here.  Apparently there might be even cleaner ways to do this than text properties. Unfortunately my _lisp foo_ is a bit limited.  See [this thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/74644/focus=76225).

Comment: That is an interesting idea, but it doesn't look less messy to me ;) It means advising or changing org-core code. post-command-hook is pretty clean I think. If there is any problem, the hook function gets kicked out automatically.

Comment: I had to add `(when (string-equal major-mode "org-mode")...` in the `link-message` function to avoid an error when non-org buffers are opened.